# How to determine if a cell has an image using google sheet formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I use a google sheet formula to determine whether a cell contains an image? I don't mean cells that have formulas such as =image(url), but rather cells that have just an image imbedded in the cell.

I've tried many things (=isText(), =isNumber() =isFormula(), =isNA(), =isURL(), =isBlank(), =isNonText()), but the closest I've been able to come up with is to combine isNumber() and isNonText() within an XOR().  However, as shown in the animated .gif (where A1 is a blank cell), this doesn't distinguish a cell containing an image from a blank cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this may work:

```
=(A3<>"")*(NOT(ISTEXT(A3)))*(NOT(ISNUMBER(A3)))=1
```

[image]

---

but note that you would need to use all possible states to really make sure ...so:

```
=ISNONTEXT(A3)*
 (NOT(ISBLANK(A3)))*
 (NOT(ISNUMBER(A3*1)))*
 (NOT(ISERROR(A3)))*
 (NOT(ISTEXT(A3)))*
 (NOT(ISFORMULA(A3)))=1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post. I applaud the exhaustive formulas you came up with to "really make sure". However this is essentially what I wrote in within my original post: "the closest I've been able to come up with is to combine isNumber() and isNonText() within an XOR(). However, ...this doesn't distinguish ...a blank cell". It's true that you put it into formula form, and I too did that, I just didn't include it (=xor(isNumber(A1),isNonText(A1),isblank(A1)) because it seems so complicated. So, the unspoken point of my question is, "Isn't there an easier, simpler way?"

Comment: no, there is no easier way unless you would write a script... (then you could do just `=ISIMAGE(A3)`). also, your XOR formula is incorrect logic wise. if you are trying to detect image apart from numbers, text and empty cells use 1st suggested formula - otherwise use 2nd one if you seek bulletproof solution. also, no need to include anything else like ISURL, ISEMAIL (ISTEXT will cover these), ISDATE, ISODD, ISEVEN, ISLOGICAL (A3*1 will cover these), ISREF, ISNA, ISERR (IFERROR will cover these)